# When does Jane Eyre return to Thornfield Hall after she runs away?

Tags: ending, jane-eyre

Towards the end of the movie, [Jane Eyre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Eyre_%282011_film%29), she runs away from her fiancee's house after discovering he is already married. 
However, she returns after realising her love and inability to be without him. 
How long is she away from Thornfield Hall and Mr Rochester before she returns?

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you? If not, what sort of information would you like to see?

Answer (score 1):

[This timeline](http://eyreguide.awardspace.co.uk/extras.html) is what you are after:

To quote some specific dates:

> 1829
>   July:
>   Thursday, 23rd: The wedding; Bertha is revealed; Jane runs away
>   in the night
>   Friday, 24th: Early in the morning, Jane boards the coach
>   Sunday, 26th: Jane arrives at Whitcross, spends the night in the heath

So she leaves on the 23rd July, 1829

> 1830
>   June:
>   Thursday, 3rd: Jane arrives at the Rochester arms, goes to Thornfield,
>   returns to the inn and hears what has happened; before dark she
>   arrives at Ferndean and reunites with Mr. Rochester.

So she returns on 3rd June, 1830

So to answer your question:

It is **316** days from the start date to the end date, end date included
Or **10 months, 12 days** including the end date

Note:
I've taken these details from the book, not the movie - I am logically assuming, even if the movie isn't explicit, it is following the same timeline.